# EF Core 5.0 -NoOnConfiguring parameter in Scaffold command is still creating OnConfiguring method

Tags: entity-framework-core, ef-core-5.0

I am trying to use -NoOnconfiguring parameter as part of my scaffold command as below using EF Core 5.0.5 version expecting not to generate OnConfiguring() in my generated DBContext class. But still I am seeing the method generated.

```
 Scaffold-DbContext "data source=TestDBSStage.nreca.org;initial catalog=xxxxx;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True" -Provider Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models\TestDBContext -Tables "Table1","Table2","Table3" -ContextDir Models\TestDBContext -Context "TestDBContextScaffold" -NoOnConfiguring -UseDatabaseNames -DataAnnotations -Force
```

Can someone help me solving this?

Thank you.

Comment: If it doesn't work as expected only the makers of the source code can help you.

Comment: Have you installed any extensions or are you customizing any design-time services? Please [create an new issue](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/new/choose) with enough information to dig into it.